# The size of two similar matrices

Tags: matrices

Show that if B is similar to A, then they are both square matrices of the same size.

If someone could get me started in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Comment: What is the meaning of being similar?

Comment: The definition of similar matrices is that $B = X^{-1} A X$ and that $A,B$ are square matrices. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: $X$ must be square (in order to be invertible). Now you can conclude everything about $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to the definition of similar matrices explicitly requiring the matrices to be square. But, I suppose it's not strictly necessary. I think the essence of saying that matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, of respective sizes $m_1 \times n_1$ and $m_2 \times n_2$, is that there exists an invertible $P$ such that,
$$A_1 = P^{-1} A_2 P$$
Let $m_3 \times n_3$ be the size of $P$. The first thing to realise is that $P$ must be square in order to be invertible (for our purposes, we say $Q$ is an inverse of $P$ if $PQ$ and $QP$ are identity matrices of possibly different sizes). If we think about this in terms of linear maps, this means $P$ represents an invertible linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{m_3}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n_3}$, which is famously only possible if $m_3 = n_3$. Thus, $P$ must be square, as claimed.

For $P^{-1}A_2$ to be well-defined, we must have $n_3 = m_2$. For $A_2 P$ to be well-defined, we must have $n_2 = m_3$. Putting altogether,
$$n_2 = m_3 = n_3 = m_2,$$
so $A_2$ and $P$ are all square, and all the same sizes. Thus, so is $A_1$.

Comment: In short: $P$ must be $d\times d$. In order to fit in $P^{-1}A_2P$, $A_2$ must be $d\times d$. Hence $A_1 = P^{-1}A_2P$ is $d\times d$.